# Some browsers on some computers doesnt accept CI session data

Tags: session, codeigniter

I use CI for my website. And I have a login page. But in some browsers on some computers I can't login to the system, because no userdata is stored in browser. I can't figure out what is the difference between the (PC+Browser)s which can and can't login.

Comment: If it is about cookies, you can check if cookies are disabled or not

Answer (score 0):

If you are using database for storing your CI sessions (table ci_sessions), make sure you change the default UserAgent field to VARCHAR 250 or something like that.
Right now I think it's something rather small that doesn't accomodate the entire UserAgent.
That way, I think the browser isn't identified

A second cause could be that you need to open config/config.php and edit this section

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "prefix";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "localhost";
$config['cookie_path']  = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = TRUE;
```

And change

```
$config['cookie_domain']    = "YOUR_DOMAIN";
```

Make sure YOUR_DOMAIN is a valid domain that your website is running on. Do not use IPs or localhost.